# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in index.php on line 73

Tags: php, html

```
<?php session_start(); 

?>

<?php

require 'connect.php';

require 'core.php';

?>

<html>

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

<title>Donor's Login</title>

 <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<?php


    if(isset($_POST['donoruname']) && isset($_POST['donorpass']))

    {
            $username=$_POST['donoruname'];

            $password=$_POST['donorpass'];

            $password_hash= md5 ($password);
    }

    if(!empty($username) && !empty($password))
    {

        $query= "SELECT `donorid` FROM `info` WHERE `donoruname`='$username' 
`donorpass`='$password_hash' ";

        if($query_run=mysql_query($query))
        {
                $query_num_rows=mysql_num_rows($query_run);

                if($query_num_rows=0)
                {
                    echo "<script>alert('Wrong id or password');</script>";
                }
                else if($query_num_rows=1)
                {
                    echo "<script>alert('Welcome you are now logging in');</script> " ;
                }

}

    else
        {
            echo '<script>alert("enter username and password");</script>';
        }



?>
<div class="login">

<form class="span4" action="index.php" method="post">  

  <fieldset class="span3">

    <legend>Donor's Login</legend>

     Username<span class="required">*</span><br>

    <input type="text" name="uname" size="30" height="24px" placeholder="Username..."><br/>

     Password<span class="required">*</span><br>

     <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password..."><br/>

     <button type="submit" name="login" class="btn">Login</button>

     <a href="register.php" class="btn btn-primary">Register</a>


  </fieldset>

</form>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

here i wrote the same php code from the video which i seen , but in video it successfully runs but in this cod it seems error like

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in index.php on line 73

Comment: check any space or not closing php tag in included file connect.php and core.php

Comment: And you can not compare like that:
`if($query_num_rows=0)`, it should be `if($query_num_rows==0)`

Comment: Your `if(!empty($username) && !empty($password))` is missing a closing brace `}` *fast huh*?

Comment: Errors as such don't necessarily mean they're on "that" line.

Comment: Sidenote: Don't use MD5 for password storage. It's no longer considered safe to use.

Answer (score 2):

You were missing a closing bracket **`}`** in your php. Try this:

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['donoruname']) && isset($_POST['donorpass'])) {
    $username = $_POST['donoruname'];

    $password = $_POST['donorpass'];

    $password_hash = md5($password);
}

if (!empty($username) && !empty($password)) {

    $query = "SELECT `donorid` FROM `info` WHERE `donoruname`='$username' 
`donorpass`='$password_hash' ";

    if ($query_run = mysql_query($query)) {
        $query_num_rows = mysql_num_rows($query_run);

        if ($query_num_rows = 0) {
            echo "<script>alert('Wrong id or password');</script>";
        } else if ($query_num_rows = 1) {
            echo "<script>alert('Welcome you are now logging in');</script> ";
        }
    } else {
        echo '<script>alert("enter username and password");</script>';
    }
}
?>
```

**EDIT:** As suggested in the comments (really just pointing out my stupidity :P). You forgot to close off one of your if statements with its corresponding bracket **`}`**. Namely ; you forgot to close of this specific if check:

```
if (isset($_POST['donoruname']) && isset($_POST['donorpass']))
```

Which resulted in your error message:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in index.php on line 73

I hope that clarifies it more :)

**EDIT #2:** It seems my guardian angel is watching over my SO actions haha !

But honestly he is correct, MD5 hashing has become redundant.

#### Why Not {MD5, SHA1, SHA256, SHA512, SHA-3, etc}?

*A modern server can calculate the MD5 hash of about 330MB every second. If your users have passwords which are lowercase, alphanumeric, and 6 characters long, you can try every single possible password of that size in around 40 seconds.* - Taken from [How to safely store a password.](http://codahale.com/how-to-safely-store-a-password/)

More reading:
[Why you shouldn't use SHA1 or MD5...](http://www.bentasker.co.uk/blog/security/201-why-you-should-be-asking-how-your-passwords-are-stored)

- Read up on [**CRYPT_BLOWFISH**](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/36471) also.
- If your PHP version is 5.5, you can benefit from using the [`password_hash()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function.

---

**Footnotes:**

`mysql_*` functions deprecation notice:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.mysql.php

This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and is not recommended for writing new code as it will be removed in the future. Instead, either the [**mysqli**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO_MySQL**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also the [**MySQL API Overview**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for further help while choosing a MySQL API.

These functions allow you to access MySQL database servers. More information about MySQL can be found at » http://www.mysql.com/.

Documentation for MySQL can be found at » http://dev.mysql.com/doc/.

Comment: It would be beneficial for the OP and future readers to indicate exactly where the missing brace is and where you placed it. *"Try this"* isn't much information.

Comment: Ah, much better. Will +1 because it's the most likely and only reason. Mentioning the fact about using MD5 would be an added bonus ;-)

Comment: Very good. I also added a few links. Now this... is an answer! ;-)

Comment: You're welcome, always glad to help out. Oh, I added a deprecation notice too about `mysql_*` to give it more "meat" or "oomf !" as we say ;-)